# Spring Boot Security Displays page as Not Secured

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I want to have a homepage followed by login page,Since the login page is not authorised the page becomes UnSecured as per my understanding.The code for this as below:

Home.html

```
<h2>1. Visit <a th:href="@{/admin}">Admin page (Spring Security protected, Need Admin Role)</a></h2>`enter code here`
                <h2>2. Visit <a th:href="@{/user}">User page (Spring Security protected, Need User Role)</a></h2>
                <h2>3. Visit <a th:href="@{/about}">Normal page</a></h2>
```

Here the login page will become unsecured because it is not authorised by spring boot security.How can I tackle the below scenario

```
 http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home", "/about").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyRole("USER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler);
```

'

Please help.Is this possible using Spring Boot Security using the above method?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by setting the following properties in application.properties
server.use-forward-headers=true